# the status is not updated

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I bring up the favorite status from API, and it appears that it is saved in favorites, but only when I  restart the application it just does not save the favorite status.

**
this is when I click the button**:

[image]

**when i run the app**

[image]

**This debuging**

[image]

**the ui code:**

```
`
class CustomListItems extends GetView<ItemsControllerImp> {
  final ItemsModel itemsModel;
  // final bool active;
  const CustomListItems({Key? key, required this.itemsModel}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          controller.goToPageProductDetails(itemsModel);
        },
        child: Card(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [ 
                  Hero(
                    tag: "${itemsModel.itemsId}",
                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                      imageUrl:
                          AppLink.imagestItems + "/" + itemsModel.itemsImage!,
                      height: 100,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Text(
                      translateDatabase(
                          itemsModel.itemsNameAr, itemsModel.itemsName),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: AppColor.black,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      const Text("Rating 3.5 ", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        height: 22,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            ...List.generate(
                                5,
                                (index) => const Icon(
                                      Icons.star,
                                      size: 15,
                                    ))
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text("${itemsModel.itemsPrice} \$",
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              color: AppColor.primaryColor,
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontFamily: "sans")),
                      GetBuilder<FavoriteController>(
                              builder: (controller) => IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    if (controller.isFavorite[itemsModel.itemsId] ==
                                        "1") {
                                      controller.setFavorite(
                                          itemsModel.itemsId, "0");
                                      controller
                                          .removeFavorite(itemsModel.itemsId!);
                                    } else {
                                      controller.setFavorite(
                                          itemsModel.itemsId, "1");
                                      controller.addFavorite(itemsModel.itemsId!);
                                    }
                                  },
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    controller.isFavorite[itemsModel.itemsId] == "1"
                                        ? Icons.favorite
                                        : Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                                    color: AppColor.primaryColor,
                                  )))
                    ],
                  )
                ]),
          ),
        ));
  }
}


`
```

**favorite controller:**

```
class FavoriteController extends GetxController {
  FavoriteData favoriteData = FavoriteData(Get.find());
  

  List data = [];

  late StatusRequest statusRequest;

  MyServices myServices = Get.find();

  Map isFavorite = {};

//  key => id items
//  Value => 1 OR 0

  setFavorite(id, val) {
    isFavorite[id] = val;
    update();
  }

  addFavorite(String itemsid) async {
    data.clear();
    statusRequest = StatusRequest.loading;
    var response = await favoriteData.addFavorite(
        myServices.sharedPreferences.getString("id")!, itemsid);
    print("=============================== Controller $response ");
    statusRequest = handlingData(response);
    if (StatusRequest.success == statusRequest) {
      // Start backend
      if (response['status'] == "success") {
        Get.rawSnackbar(
            title: "اشعار",
            messageText: const Text("تم اضافة المنتج من المفضلة "));
        // data.addAll(response['data']);
      } else {
        statusRequest = StatusRequest.failure;
      }
      // End

    }
  }

  removeFavorite(String itemsid) async {
    data.clear();
    statusRequest = StatusRequest.loading;
    var response = await favoriteData.removeFavorite(
        myServices.sharedPreferences.getString("id")!, itemsid);
    print("=============================== Controller $response ");
    statusRequest = handlingData(response);
    if (StatusRequest.success == statusRequest) {
      // Start backend
      if (response['status'] == "success") {
        Get.rawSnackbar(
            title: "اشعار",
            messageText: const Text("تم حذف المنتج من المفضلة "));
        // data.addAll(response['data']);
      } else {
        statusRequest = StatusRequest.failure;
      }
      // End
    }
  }
}
```

the api It returns 1, meaning that it was stored in the data base and there is no problem with the back and forth

Comment: Why is it tagged with PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for String `object == "1"`. In the Debugger it seems like an integer `object == 1`.

I think in your app you are storing it as an String, but when you store it, it stores as an integer.

Comment: i conver it toString in ItemsModel bro

Comment: try this, then you can be sure: (controller.isFavorite[itemsModel.itemsId] == "1" || controller.isFavorite[itemsModel.itemsId] == 1) : ..... ? ....;